# Why doesn't the DestroyWindow() free the memory in my code?

Tags: c++, windows, handle

So this is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cin.get();    //MEMORY SNAP
    HWND win = CreateWindow(
        "static",
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP | WS_DISABLED,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        GetConsoleWindow(),
        (HMENU)0,
        GetModuleHandle(0),
        NULL
        );
    cin.get();    //MEMORY SNAP
    DestroyWindow(win);
    cin.get();    //MEMORY SNAP
}
```

basically I'm only creating a window and then destroying it.
So all the memory allocated by the window should be freed,
but my memory looks like this -> http://oi67.tinypic.com/2rwrsxc.jpg
it won't get fully deleted and i don't know why.

I'd be really happy if you could help me with this one.

---

Image from link:

[image]

Comment: The memory if free'd up, but the operating system keeps it mapped to your process until it needs it.

Comment: So is there no way to get rid of it?

Comment: You *have* gotten rid of it. After the `DestroyWindow` call the memory is available to be allocated again. And if your system get low on virtual memory then the OS will grab those pages and give to other processes.

Comment: Oh okay. Now i know whats going on there. I thought DestroyWindow had failed, but it destroied it and kept the memory in my program. So confusing that Diagnostic Session doesn't tell me x) Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why free() doesn't really frees memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139436/why-free-doesnt-really-frees-memory)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at two different numbers. `DestroyWindow` releases memory, but not directly back to the OS. It remains available to your program. Practically speaking, that means that the **next** `CreateWindow` call does **not increase** memory consumption, as it recycles memory.

Answer (score 1):

While memory usage is not necessarily a good measure, the odds that a single release frees up enough contiguous VM space to make it worthwhile to return it to the OS are never good, the displayed allocation count should be trustworthy.  The implementation detail that matters here is that windows are allocated in the desktop heap.  A shared heap that is used by all processes that run on that desktop.  It is not tracked by the memory profiler.

The allocation count increase you see is related to *other* things that happen when you create a window.  Like the message queue that is needed to supply it with messages, it is dynamically allocated.  It doesn't get released until the owner thread ends.  Beware that the notion of a "queue" is just a mental model, the actual implementation is undocumented and much more involved.  So much more than just one allocation.

Never fret about memory usage that is beyond your control.  The OS can be trusted to not suffer from leaks.