# Memory leak when calling C.malloc/C.free in goroutines

Tags: go, malloc, cgo

I'm seeing a constant memory leak when I look at RSS with the following trivial program:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
    "time"
    "unsafe"
    )

func loopStuff() {
    for {
        ptrs := make([]unsafe.Pointer, 20)
        for i:=0; i<20; i++ {
            ptrs[i] = C.malloc(16 * (1 << i))
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        for i:=0; i<20; i++ {
            C.free(ptrs[i])
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        go loopStuff()
    }
    loopStuff()
}
```

I'm on go 1.13.4 and ubuntu 18.04.
What is going on here?

Comment: You are right that this code should not leak memory.  How are you determining that you have a leak?  How long did you run the code for?  Note that the resident set size may not reduce until the OS needs the memory.

Comment: It's at 640M resident according to top, and still rising albeit a bit slower now. The peak theoretical memory allocated is around 80M if I got it right, so this is definitely much higher than expected.

Comment: It seems to happen with standard malloc and also tcmalloc. Does not happen with tbbmalloc though

Comment: For me, it's 3KB at start and growing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies with the `for {}` loop that is indefinitely running for each of the 10+1 goroutines.

Also if you read about `free`:

```
Deallocates the space previously allocated by malloc(), calloc(), aligned_alloc(), (since C11) or realloc().
```

So it basically deallocates the space and not necessarily returns memory back to the operating system immediately. Also, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139468/5821408).

As the `for loop` is running indefinitely you'll definitely see a rise in memory which is not a leak though. I've modified your code by removing the `for loop`. And then I checked the RSS using BSD's `top` and it's using an averge of 1100KB and not rising. Maybe after waiting for sometime, it'll even reduce (when memory is returned back to the OS).

Tested with: `OS: MacOS, Go: 1.15`

BSD's `top` output:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH  #WQ  #POR MEM   PURG CMPR PGRP  PPID  STATE
30767  cgo          0.0  00:00.00 11   0    20   1144K 0B   0B   30767 29146 sleeping
```

Code:

```golang
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import "unsafe"

func loopStuff() {
        ptrs := make([]unsafe.Pointer, 20)
        for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
                ptrs[i] = C.malloc(16 * (1 << i))
        }
        for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
                C.free(ptrs[i])
        }
}

func main() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                go loopStuff()
        }
        loopStuff()
        // Block the main goroutine
        select {}
}
```

Update:

Try the following code. There was definitely allocation for a slice of `unsafe.Pointer` in every iteration. Also made a couple of changes. Perhaps on your system you won't see a memory leak now.

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
        "time"
        "unsafe"
)

func loopStuff() {
        ptrs := make([]*unsafe.Pointer, 20)
        for {
                for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
                        tmp := C.malloc(16 * (1 << i))
                        ptrs[i] = &tmp
                }
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
                for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
                        C.free(*ptrs[i])
                }
        }
}

func main() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                go loopStuff()
        }
        loopStuff()
}
```

Comment: If you remove the infinite loop, it seems obvious that a finite program will not allocate indefinitely. This does not seem to answer the OP question though.

Comment: That's why I explained the behaviour of `free` as well. It's not a leak.

Comment: But here, the program should require a finite amount of memory. What I measure using the OP code is that malloc keeps asking new memory blocs from the OS and never releases it

Comment: This might be relevant: https://lemire.me/blog/2020/03/03/calling-free-or-delete/
Also, it takes to release the memory back to OS and it depends on the OS as well. I'd suggest you to stop requesting for memory at a point and monitor the RSS for a few mins.

Comment: But why is the allocator not reusing memory instead of asking for new memory from the system. I'm clear on the fact that free is not required to release the memory back to the system. However, I expect the allocator to reuse memory. It's one of its key responsibilities.

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Hey could you please try the updated code. It should work for you!

Comment: I tried your version and the issue is still there. In the meantime, I managed to reproduce this behavior without Go in c++ and identify more clearly how to trigger it. First, the memory must be allocated in one thread and de-allocated in another thread. Second, the memory must not be changed by the program. Simply adding a bzero fixes the issue

Comment: But for me, it was working. Always under 11MB. But glad you figured it out.